# finding an element in a 2d vector and then removing it

Tags: c++

Let's say I have my data in a 4 by 3 `vector<vector<int> >` as:

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
10  11  12
```

and I want to delete every row containing the element `8` and end up like:

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
10  11  12
```

I have been trying to do:

```
for (vector<vector<int> >::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
    if (find(it->begin(), it->end(), 8)) {
        // I will remove the row in here
    }
}
```

which gives me:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'find(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator, int)'
```

I don't have much experience with `stl` so I was wondering:

- what's wrong with my `find` call?
- is it safe to remove an element from a vector while iterating over it?

Ofc any elegant solution to my problem is also welcomed..

Comment: `find` looks for an element. Your outer vector's elements are vectors, not ints. You'd probably be best using the erase-remove idiom in conjunction with `std::remove_if`.

Comment: @chris yes, but `it::operator->` returns the inner vector, so this should be ok. Besides, the error message suggests it's just a matter of missing include.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, Missed that one. You're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what's wrong with my find call?

You probably forgot to `#include <algorithm>`

> is it safe to remove an element from a vector while iterating over it?

Look into the erase-remove idiom - erasing vector elements can be tricky.

Comment: `#include <algorithm>` has worked, now I've got another error.

Comment: @gokcehan if it's completely different, please post a new question.

Comment: it's completely different but I think I will try to use erase-remove idioms instead, looks much easier..

Comment: This is why I don't use iterators for `vector`s, even though I probably should.